# How do I Get the Token I Need to for my Script to hit my Azure Stored Procedure?

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

I have an azure stored procedure, and I need to hit it with a python script that I'm going to upload as a webjob to schedule it to run once per day.

I've been reading the docs on [executing a stored procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/execute-a-stored-procedure), the [common request headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/common-cosmosdb-rest-request-headers) for Azure Cosmos DB rest calls, and the page on [access control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/access-control-on-cosmosdb-resources?redirectedfrom=MSDN), but the access control page mentions that these keys are for read queries only (so I assume not for hitting stored procedures, which have rights to do any sort of query or else that seems like a huge vulnerability hole).

I need to know specifically how do I get a key from Azure in python to hit my stored procedure endpoint?

### Update 1

I was able, finally, to construct the Authorization string and send it, along with some other headers, to the server. But I am still getting an unauthorized response.

The response:

```
{
    "code": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "The input authorization token can't serve the request. Please check that the expected payload is built as per the protocol, and check the key being used. Server used the following payload to sign: 'post\nsprocs\ndbs/metrics/colls/LoungeVisits/sprocs/calculateAverage\nfri, 05 oct 2018 19:06:17 gmt\n\n'\r\nActivityId: 41cd36af-ad0e-40c3-84c8-761ebd14bf6d, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.1.0.0"
}
```

The request headers:

```
{
    Authorization: [my-auth-string],
    x-ms-version: "2017-02-22", //My DB was created after this, the latest version, so I assume it uses this version; can I verify this somehow?
    x-ms-date: "Fri, 05 Oct 2018 19:06:17 GMT", // My js for returning the auth string also returns the date, so I copy both in
    Content-Type: application/json
}
```

Code to generate auth string which is then copy/pasted into Postman:

```
var crypto = require("crypto");

var inputKey = "my-key-from-azure";

var today = new Date().toUTCString();

console.log(today);

console.log(getAuthorizationTokenUsingMasterKey("POST", "dbs", "dbs/ToDoList", today, inputKey))

function getAuthorizationTokenUsingMasterKey(verb, resourceType, resourceId, date, masterKey) 
 {  
    var key = new Buffer(masterKey, "base64");  

    var text = (verb || "").toLowerCase() + "\n" +   
           (resourceType || "").toLowerCase() + "\n" +   
           (resourceId || "") + "\n" +   
           date.toLowerCase() + "\n" +   
           "" + "\n";  

    var body = new Buffer(text, "utf8");  
    var signature = crypto.createHmac("sha256", key).update(body).digest("base64");  

    var MasterToken = "master";  

    var TokenVersion = "1.0";  

    return encodeURIComponent("type=" + MasterToken + "&ver=" + TokenVersion + "&sig=" + signature);  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The page about [authorization headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/access-control-on-cosmosdb-resources?redirectedfrom=MSDN) is for any Cosmos DB REST request: query, stored procedures, etc.

Comment: Okay, I built the Authorization string using the guide, but now I'm getting "The input authorization token can't serve the request. Please check that the expected payload is built as per the protocol, and check the key being used." I've triple-checked the protocol and used both the primary and secondary key to build it. Is there a different key I should use?

Answer (score 0):

Azure cosmos DB has [python SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sdk-python) which is the recommended and supported way for such scenarios.

Also python SDK code is open-sourced. Here is the reference to auth header creation code [enter link description here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-python/blob/master/azure/cosmos/auth.py)